# Calculating on objects in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to make a function that calculates the percentage of "completed tasks" in a recursive manner.

Here's what I have now, but this only calculates the percentage on the parent, not grandparent etc:

```js
const tasks = [
    { id: 1, task: 'Clean apartment', completed: null, parentId: null},
    { id: 2, task: 'Make app', completed: null, parentId: null},
    { id: 3, task: 'Clean bathroom', completed: null, parentId: 1},
    { id: 4, task: 'Clean kitchen', completed: null, parentId: 1},
    { id: 5, task: 'Wash sink', completed: true, parentId: 3},
    { id: 6, task: 'Wash shower', completed: null, parentId: 3},
    { id: 7, task: 'Wash glass panes', completed: null, parentId: 6},
    { id: 8, task: 'Wash floor', completed: null, parentId: 6},
]

function compileTask(tasks, taskId) {
    var task = (typeof taskId === 'number') ? tasks.find(task => task.id === taskId) : taskId;
    var children = tasks.filter(t => t.parentId === task.id);

    task.percent = children.filter(c => c.completed === true).length / children.length * 100


    task.children = children.map(child => compileTask(tasks, child));
    return task
}

console.log(compileTask(tasks, 1))
```

As you see, task id 3 is 50% completed because one of the two child tasks are marked completed, but task id 1 is 0% completed. If I'm calculating right in my head, task id 1 should return 25% completed.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of the output format you want, so I'm going to generate something like the following.  We can probably alter it to fit your needs:

```js
[
  {id: 1, task: 'Clean apartment', percent: 25, parentId: null}
  {id: 2, task: 'Make app', percent: 0, parentId: null}
  {id: 3, task: 'Clean bathroom', percent: 50, parentId: 1}
  {id: 4, task: 'Clean kitchen', percent: 0, parentId: 1}
  {id: 5, task: 'Wash sink', percent: 100, parentId: 3}
  {id: 6, task: 'Wash shower', percent: 0, parentId: 3}
  {id: 7, task: 'Wash glass panes', percent: 0, parentId: 6}
  {id: 8, task: 'Wash floor', percent: 0, parentId: 6}
]
```

### Initial Approach

This is a fairly simple recursive technique:

```js
const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const findPercent = (task, tasks, children = tasks .filter (({parentId}) => task .id == parentId)) => 
  children .length 
    ? sum (children .map (c => findPercent(c, tasks))) / children .length
    : task .completed ? 100 : 0

const compileTasks = (tasks) => tasks .map (
  (task, _, __, {completed, parentId, ...rest} = task) => ({
    ...rest, 
    percent: findPercent (task, tasks), 
    parentId
  })
)

const tasks = [{id: 1, task: 'Clean apartment', completed: null, parentId: null}, {id: 2, task: 'Make app', completed: null, parentId: null}, {id: 3, task: 'Clean bathroom', completed: null, parentId: 1}, {id: 4, task: 'Clean kitchen', completed: null, parentId: 1}, {id: 5, task: 'Wash sink', completed: true, parentId: 3}, {id: 6, task: 'Wash shower', completed: null, parentId: 3}, {id: 7, task: 'Wash glass panes', completed: null, parentId: 6}, {id: 8, task: 'Wash floor', completed: null, parentId: 6}]

console .log (compileTasks (tasks))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`findPercent` is a helper function that recursively looks through the children, and averages their percentages.  It bottoms out when there are no children, and then chooses 0% or 100% depending upon whether the task is `completed`.  It uses a trivial `sum` helper, which adds up an array of numbers.

The main function is `compileTasks`.  It simply maps the list of tasks to slightly altered versions, removing `completed` and adding `percent`, which is found by calling `findPercent`.

There is a potential problem with this technique, though.  It doesn't matter at all for small tests, but there is a lot of work that is done multiple times.  We average the percentages of 7 and 8, when building 1, then do it again when building 3, and again when building 6.  This is problematic, and so I will suggest a:

### More Performant Approach

The problem here is that our flat list is not the best way to track what is fundamentally a tree structure.  This would be much easier to work with:

```js
[
    {id: 1, task: "Clean apartment", completed: null, children: [
        {id: 3, task: "Clean bathroom", completed: null, children: [
            {id: 5, task: "Wash sink", completed: true},
            {id: 6, task: "Wash shower", completed: null, children: [
                {id: 7, task: "Wash glass panes", completed: null},
                {id: 8, task: "Wash floor", completed: null}
            ]}
        ]},
        {id: 4, task: "Clean kitchen", completed: null}
    ]},
    {id: 2, task: "Make app", completed: null}
]
```

I would suggest that you consider using this more useful structure internally all the time, and only using the flat list for storage.   But if you can't, do this,  then we can convert back and forth between the two structure, and do your calculations on that nicer tree structure.  It might look like this:

```js
const sum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const nest = (tasks, parent = null) =>
  tasks .filter (({parentId}) => parentId === parent) .map (
    ({id, parentId, ...rest}, _, __, children = nest (tasks, id)) => ({
      id, ...rest, ...(children.length ? {children} : {})
    }))

const unnest = (nodes, parentId = null) => [
  ...nodes .map (({children, ...rest}) => ({...rest, parentId})),  
  ...nodes .flatMap (node => unnest (node .children || [], node.id))
]

const calcPcts = (tasks) =>
  tasks .map (({completed, children = [], ...rest}, _, __, kids = calcPcts (children)) => ({
    ... rest,
    ... (kids .length 
          ? {percent: sum (kids .map (k => k.percent)) / kids .length, children: kids} 
          : {percent: completed ? 100 : 0}
        )
  }))

const compileTasks = (tasks) => 
  unnest (calcPcts (nest (tasks)))

const tasks = [{id: 1, task: 'Clean apartment', completed: null, parentId: null}, {id: 2, task: 'Make app', completed: null, parentId: null}, {id: 3, task: 'Clean bathroom', completed: null, parentId: 1}, {id: 4, task: 'Clean kitchen', completed: null, parentId: 1}, {id: 5, task: 'Wash sink', completed: true, parentId: 3}, {id: 6, task: 'Wash shower', completed: null, parentId: 3}, {id: 7, task: 'Wash glass panes', completed: null, parentId: 6}, {id: 8, task: 'Wash floor', completed: null, parentId: 6}]

console .log (compileTasks (tasks))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here, after the `sum` helper, we have a `nest` function that converts your flat list into that tree structure, and an `unnest` function that converts it such a tree back into the flat list.

Our main function is `compileTasks`, which simply composes these two functions and runs the core function `calcPcts` between them to generate this intermediate format:

```js
[
    {id: 1, task: "Clean apartment", percent: 25, children: [
        {id: 3, task: "Clean bathroom", percent: 50, children: [
            {id: 5, task: "Wash sink", percent: 100},
            {id: 6, task: "Wash shower", percent: 0, children: [
                {id: 7, task: "Wash glass panes", percent: 0},
                {id: 8, task: "Wash floor", percent: 0}
            ]}
        ]},
        {id: 4, task: "Clean kitchen", percent: 0}
    ]},
    {id: 2, task: "Make app", percent: 0}
]
```

And now we need to discuss `calcPcts`.  This works much like above, except that because we're calling top-down, and rolling up the results from the bottom up, we don't have to  re-call it for nested nodes.

One interesting thing about this approach is that you can reuse `nest` and `unnest` around other recursive node conversion techniques.  The roll-up from `completed` to `percent` is isolated in that one place, but the overall mechanism is shared.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Sorry for my late respons, there was a lot to go through.

I've been thinking about performance for this project. First I tried making the "tasks" nested, but I had trouble adding tasks etc because my lack of experience in recursive thinking.

I ended up making this flat structure assuming I'm gonna use a mysql database. Do you think a nosql database would be better? 

In the end I would like my webserver to return a nested structure of the tasks.

Comment: Not at all a slow response (and that should never be a worry on StackOverflow anyway.) How you choose to store your data is far too complex a topic to decide in a short chat. But these days you do have good choices for Object stores if you like. If you do store it flat, I would recommend that you use something like `nest` as soon as you retrieve it, use the tree format for your application code, and only use the `unnest` when you go to store it back. The tree is much easier to work with for all sorts of cases. And in those places where it's harder, it's only *slightly* harder. Best of luck!

Comment: Hello, again! I'm having trouble making the calcPcts function accept one task instead of all tasks. If I use the function I wrote (compileTask) as the nest function, I can't use calcPcts because it expects an array (I think). Do you mind making an edit?

Comment: I'm afraid you're missing the point.  `calcPcts` operates on the **tree** structure displayed above.  It transforms a *tree* of objects with `completed` properties into a *tree* with `percent` properties. The whole idea is that it is not individual nodes which capture the information you want but the entire tree structure. My initial approach works more like you seem to want. You can use it, but it will have performance problems as the data grows.  I don't know how bad or how soon, and it may never become an issue for you, but the second approach is not only more performant: it's also cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing objects and integers.

```
var task = (typeof taskId === 'number') ? tasks.find(task => task.id === taskId) : taskId;
```

returns a task in one case and an id in another

then here

```
task.children = children.map(child => compileTask(tasks, child));
```

You are passing a child instead of the `child.id`. It should be

```
task.children = children.map(child => compileTask(tasks, child.id));
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed that! Seems to have been working either way, though?

Do you have any tips on calculating the percentage of completed grandchild tasks?